# pydbus reconnection after target is rebooted

Tags: python, glib, dbus

I'm facing the following problem.

I'm using pydbus python package to test API by connecting to a target linux machine which is in the same network by using the environment variable DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS

Under normal circumstances this works well, I'm able to call any valid API over the proxy object created.

Eg:

```py
import os
import pydbus
os.environ['DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS'] = \
          "tcp:host=192.168.1.100,port=55556,family=ipv4"
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
proxy = bus.get("busname", "object_path")
return_value = proxy.method-name(args)
```

As part of my testing, my target linux machine gets rebooted in between and when I re-use the proxy object, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/harman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydbus/proxy.py", line 47, in get
0, timeout_to_glib(timeout), None)
GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: The connection is closed (18)
```

I realize that the previous connection no longer exists, so I tried re-initialising the connection with the following

```
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
proxy = bus.get("busname", "object_path")
```

I get the same error on the bus.get() statement.

Is there a solution/possible workaround to this problem?